# Wordpress Rewrite_Rule to allow '/page/value'

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a page called 'all-products' on Wordpress, and I want to get products using id in the url as `domain.com/all-products/4382zcxs2133`

```
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'routeparam';
    return $public_query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');

function do_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('all-products/[a-zA-Z0-9]/?$', 'index.php?pagename=all-products&routeparam=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');
```

Then, when I tried using `$wp_query->query_vars['routeparam']`, it says 'undefined index'.

When I `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars)`, I can actually see the value in an index called page but that only works for numbers. If I use letters and numbers instead, I get 404 error.

---

Edit:

`/all-products/213213` - works

`/all-products/` - works

`/all-products/21321dsa3fsa` - doesn't work

I tried the regex on a fiddle, it works, but on Wordpress in `add_rewrite_rule`, it doesn't work.

---

Edit 2:

I've commented out my write rule line, and it looks like it can still access `product/123` so somehow, my rewrite rule is not registering.

I tried `var_dump($wp_rewrite)` and I can confirm that my rewrite rule is registered but I believe that default wordpress pagination ('pagination_base' exactly) may cause this.

Because when I comment out add write rule and visit the url through `/all-products/123`, I can still access the page without a 404 and I can see that '123' value I have provided is shown as 'page' in `$wp_query->query_vars`.

Comment: You say `all-products`, but in your tests you use `/products/` - are you sure you are correctly testing the rule? You can use `'all-products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'` or `'products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'`, perhaps even `'^products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'`. Note the parentheses. And  note: [*Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, it was a typo in the question 'products' = 'all-products'. I didn't know that I need to re-save permalinks from settings, checking it now.. **Edit:** Omg, that was it!! Huge thanks man!!!

Comment: So, did `'products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'
```

or if this part is always at the beginning, add `^`:

```
'^products(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?/?$'
```

Note the `+` and `(...)` parentheses around `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` that form Group 1 and its value will be used via `$matches[1]`.

And [*Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).